# Parse XML object in the context of another object in Xstrem

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<people>
    <person name="John" id="1">...</person>
    .....
    <person name="Mark" id="3421">
        <father references="1" />
    </person>
</people>
```

And I have created the following `Xstream` object:

```
XStream configXstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
configXstream.alias("people", People.class);
configXstream.alias("person", Person.class);
```

I have parsed an existing XML to a `People` object. Now I want at runtime to add a person from an XML, and refer to its father which is in the existing `People` object. For example, I want to add the following:

```
<person name="Peter" id="3459">
    <father references="3421" />
</person>
```

Now I can't parse the XML to a person object because it says that the reference to the father is invalid.

Is there a way to tell xstream to parse an object given the context (the object from which it should resolve references?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom converter which scans the list of people for a given id. To do that, I extended the `Converter` class and then registered it using `xstream.registerConverter(new MyAwesomeCustomConverter)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember XStream is based on a stream model. It processes the XML from top to bottom. Therefore is is possible to add backward references (i.e to persons that were already processed), but forward references cannot be resolved at all.